# media query is not working, is there a limit per page?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive, limit

When i make the responsive of my web-site,
some media query works but the last ones don't.

```css
/* work */
@media screen and (max-width: 1030px){

    .section2 .content-card .title-card img {
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    .section1 {
        height: 1000px;
    }
}

/* doesn't work */

@media screen and (max-width: 1030px){
    .section2 {
        padding-top: 15vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 260px){
    .section2 {
        padding-top: 6vh;
    }

    .section1 {
        padding-top: 3vh;
    }
}
```

In my code there are many more media queries but I had to remove them because of the code limits on the question.

Is there a limit to the number of media queries per file?

Comment: Well, MQs does not has any limit. Could you add HTML so that I can take a look?

Comment: ok but when i asked the question, he was telling me that there was too much code for so little info so if its not working i will send you a link

Comment: Create a Codepen or a fiddle

Comment: I do not know how to do so here are google drive links

Comment: html file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DeitanjoYtm0iV91NnbYCfh0pE_6Vv5G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: css file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/10PrybrsP2SGvh5j803020_RJ0WiEnDlv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And thanks for Codepen I didn't know

Comment: looking at it. Hold on tight.

Comment: It is working as expected for me. I see changes reflected.

Comment: weird. I made 2 page and on the 2 page I have the same problem

Comment: See value in below picture in answer. It shows that section2 got 15vh padding as mentioned in MQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See attached picture. This shows that it is working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact to do the responsive, I use the responsive mode with the devtools
is that why its not working[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSQfu.png)

Comment: Well I will continue my research on my side.
Thanks for trying
goodbye

Comment: I found the solution I had to use the tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 to activate the media query